# Highcharts: Dynamically change single column width to highlight one sample

Tags: highcharts

In a Highcharts column chart we'd like to highlight one value/sample by drawing its column a little bit wider... But this seems not to be possible, is it?

`pointWidth` only affects the whole series.

Maybe I could overlay a second series, but IMHO that's not a nice solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use data attribute and modify width.

http://jsfiddle.net/cDvmy/2/

```
 chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
            width:50
        });
```

Comment: Straight-forward, so this is my preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this with the current API.  As an equally *not nice solution* you could adjust the SVG after the plot is drawn:

```
// make fifth bar of first series wider
var bar = $($('.highcharts-series').children()[4]);
bar.attr('width',parseInt(bar.attr('width'))+20);
bar.attr('x',parseInt(bar.attr('x'))-10); // keep it centered
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ffw87/).