# Highcharts multiple column bar chart with "fill" effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to have a black background for each of the bars and their titles to the left. This is what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/jimbob25/T5737/

I specify the column width using the pointWidth

```
{
        name: 'Jane',
        color: '#FF9F00',
        data: [100],
        pointWidth: 30
    }]
```

and this is what I'm trying to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aru5F.png

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the top red rect? It's just a a rect, or can be changed via value? In general, you have two options, or use Barbara's solution (then you will have categories for each bar) and red bar create using renderer. Second solution is harder, you will need to play around with threshold and x-offset for labels, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/T5737/3/

Comment: That jsfiddle is what i'm looking for now i just need to make it look like a "fill" something like this http://jsfiddle.net/L974T/4/ to make it look like the bars are being filled

Comment: Then add fake series, which will be background, disable mouse event for it and use different yAxis. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L974T/21/

Comment: Hi Pawel, I am having difficulty because in the example you showed, L974T/21 there are just 2 series of same size bars, and in the new example there are 10 series so do you mean create 10 more which will act as background?

Comment: Nope, just create the same number of fake series as different pointWidth's you used. You have 5x different size bar? Create 5 fake series.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after because you have a bunch of series each with only one data point.  But, if I were to do it, I'd use stacking:percent and have 2 series that add to 100.

```
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            stacking:'percent',
            pointWidth: 10
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [ {
         data: [15, 0,0,45,35,55,45,15,25,0]
    },{
         data: [85, 100,100,55,65,45,55,85,75,100]
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T5737/2/

Comment: Hi Barbara, thank you but I am looking for something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/L974T/4/

but i want my top bar to be 30px, larger than the rest

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613954/highcharts-dynamically-change-single-column-width-to-higlight-one-sample