# Setting the width of a single bar in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I've been trying to change the width of a single column in a bar chart created using Highcharts. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/fjsuarez/pen/obpaao).

In all the search that I did, I could only find two solutions given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613954/highcharts-dynamically-change-single-column-width-to-higlight-one-sample).

The problem with that is that since they are set dinamically after initialization, any action that calls the `redraw` method will revert their width to the calculated one.

Also, I don't understand why they are using `series[0].data[5].graphic.attr('width')` and how it affects, since I don't see such property in the object ([console screenshot](http://i68.tinypic.com/npncow.png))

Finally, in the codepen I'm also changing the color of the same point, but doing it in the initialization function. I wonder if there is a way to do the same for the width.

Am I missing something? Because I didn't find anything in the API docs and I'm clueless as to how these solutions actually work if there is no such property in the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short explanation:

- `attr` method is inherited from [`Element`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element) class. You can see that method in prototype (in console click `__proto__`). Method `attr` works in two ways: `attr(property_name)` is a getter (to get e.g. width) and `attr({ property_name: value })` is a setter (to set e.g. width). If you use source files (`.src.js`), then you would notice that `SVGElement` class.
- width will change on any `redraw` event, because it is recalculated again (like updating point, or resizing window). In fact you can use `chart.events.redraw` and there change width. In fact, I would use both, `chart.events.redraw` and `chart.events.load` with one function, to update widths.

And to explain, why you can't set width in point, like you did with color: there is not such option on point level, like `pointWidth`. You can set specific width for all points within one series only (using mentioned `pointWidth`). There is an idea for Highcharts, to add such feature (to the core or as a plugin). Feel free to vote for it on the [UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2303560-multi-dimensional-column-charts). Here is interesting example: http://jsfiddle.net/75oucp3b/14/ (works with v4.1.8)