# Differtent pattern color for every single column in highchart

Tags: highcharts

```
   defs: {
            patterns: [{
              'id': 'budget-pattern',
              'path': {
                        d: 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
                        stroke: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
                        strokeWidth: 3
                      }
             }]
          },
```

Here the stroke is hardcoded with 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)' but I want to have different stroke for every column in highchart.

thank you

Comment: Looks to be connected with this SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613954/highcharts-dynamically-change-single-column-width-to-higlight-one-sample

Answer (score 1):

You can set series's colorByPoint to true.

```
   plotOptions: {
            series: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },
```

Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.colorByPoint

OR Refer Highcharts Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-colorbypoint-true/